# Why userLocation returns (-180.0,-180.0) coordinates on Mapbox?

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, userlocation

I use **Mapbox** with Swift 4 and I have a problem when I want to display the user location. I don't understand why the user location is not set as it should be.

I would get the user location coordinates in the `viewDidLoad()` method. To do so, I have set `MGLMapViewDelegate` and `CLLocationManagerDelegate` in my **ViewController** declaration. Then, in my `viewDidLoad()` I have:

```
// Mapview configuration
let mapView = MGLMapView(frame: self.mapView.bounds)
mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
mapView.showsUserLocation = true
mapView.setUserTrackingMode(.follow, animated: true)
mapView.delegate = self

self.mapView.addSubview(mapView)

// User location        
print("User location:")
print(mapView.userLocation!.coordinate)
```

But I get this:

> CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -180.0, longitude: -180.0)

I think it is because the location is not set when the view loads, but I need to get values in `viewDidLoad()`.

What should I do, and why the line `mapView.userLocation!.coordinate` doesn't work?

---

**EDIT**

In fact, I want to use **MapboxDirections** to display on the map a line between the user location and a fixed point. To do it, I use this code **(see the first comment)**:

```
let waypoints = [
    // HERE I would use the user location coordinates for my first Waypoint
    Waypoint(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 38.9131752, longitude: -77.0324047), name: "Mapbox"),
    Waypoint(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 38.8977, longitude: -77.0365), name: "White House"),
        ]
let options = RouteOptions(waypoints: waypoints, profileIdentifier: .automobileAvoidingTraffic)
options.includesSteps = true

_ = directions.calculate(options) { (waypoints, routes, error) in
    guard error == nil else {
        print("Error calculating directions: \(error!)")
        return
    }

    if let route = routes?.first, let leg = route.legs.first {
        print("Route via \(leg):")

        let distanceFormatter = LengthFormatter()
        let formattedDistance = distanceFormatter.string(fromMeters: route.distance)

        let travelTimeFormatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
        travelTimeFormatter.unitsStyle = .short
        let formattedTravelTime = travelTimeFormatter.string(from: route.expectedTravelTime)

        print("Distance: \(formattedDistance); ETA: \(formattedTravelTime!)")

        if route.coordinateCount > 0 {
            // Convert the route’s coordinates into a polyline.
            var routeCoordinates = route.coordinates!
            let routeLine = MGLPolyline(coordinates: &routeCoordinates, count: route.coordinateCount)

            // Add the polyline to the map and fit the viewport to the polyline.
            mapView.addAnnotation(routeLine)
            mapView.setVisibleCoordinates(&routeCoordinates, count: route.coordinateCount, edgePadding: .zero, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because getting the location is asynchrone? It's unclear what you do exactly.

Comment: @Larme I updated my question, is it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Larme is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48705982/why-userlocation-returns-180-0-180-0-coordinates-on-mapbox#comment84410773_48705982): the user's location typically isn't available yet in `-viewDidLoad`. Use the [`-mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:`](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.7.3/Protocols/MGLMapViewDelegate.html#/c:objc(pl)MGLMapViewDelegate(im)mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:) delegate method to be notified when the user's location becomes available and when it updates.

If you need the user’s location before a map is shown, consider running your own [`CLLocationManager`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager).

`-180, -180` is the [`kCLLocationCoordinate2DInvalid`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/kcllocationcoordinate2dinvalid) constant from Core Location. You should typically check if `CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid()` before trying to display `CLLocationCoordinate2D` on a map.

Answer (score 0):

Sergey Kargopolov has a [great example](http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/code-examples/determine-users-current-location-example-in-swift/) of how to obtain the user location using CLLocationManager and CLLocationManagerDelegate. Here is his code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

var locationManager:CLLocationManager!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    determineMyCurrentLocation()
}


func determineMyCurrentLocation() {
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        //locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation

    // Call stopUpdatingLocation() to stop listening for location updates,
    // other wise this function will be called every time when user location changes.

   // manager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    print("user latitude = \(userLocation.coordinate.latitude)")
    print("user longitude = \(userLocation.coordinate.longitude)")
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error)
{
    print("Error \(error)")
}
}
```